# create pandas dataframe from URL

Tags: pandas

This must be easy, but I am not able to get this dataframe in the correct form.

```
df = pd.read_json('https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia.org/all-access/user/Python_(programming_language)/daily/20210101/20210501')
```

The expected columns are:

> project, article,granularity,timestamp,access,agent,user,views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.read_json('https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia.org/all-access/user/Python_(programming_language)/daily/20210101/20210501')
>>> pd.concat([df.drop(['items'], axis=1), df['items'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
          project                        article granularity   timestamp      access agent  views
0    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010100  all-access  user   7238
1    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010200  all-access  user   8449
2    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010300  all-access  user   8669
3    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010400  all-access  user  10688
4    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010500  all-access  user  11383
..            ...                            ...         ...         ...         ...   ...    ...
116  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042700  all-access  user   6125
117  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042800  all-access  user   6184
118  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042900  all-access  user   5960
119  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021043000  all-access  user   5489
120  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021050100  all-access  user   4297

[121 rows x 7 columns]
>>>
```

Comment: Why the `concat` and `drop` ? It seems that `df['items'].apply(pd.Series)` produces the same result ?

Comment: It's just a common pandas pattern. It helps when you have columns, other than the nested one, that you want to keep

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) as well -

```
>>> df = pd.read_json('https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia.org/all-access/user/Python_(programming_language)/daily/20210101/20210501')
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df.drop('items', 1).assign(**df['items'].apply(pd.Series))
          project                        article granularity   timestamp      access agent  views
0    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010100  all-access  user   7238
1    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010200  all-access  user   8449
2    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010300  all-access  user   8669
3    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010400  all-access  user  10688
4    en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021010500  all-access  user  11383
..            ...                            ...         ...         ...         ...   ...    ...
116  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042700  all-access  user   6125
117  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042800  all-access  user   6184
118  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021042900  all-access  user   5960
119  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021043000  all-access  user   5489
120  en.wikipedia  Python_(programming_language)       daily  2021050100  all-access  user   4297

[121 rows x 7 columns]
```